# Should KeyEventListener and MouseListener be in there own class?

Tags: java, swing

I have seen these done many ways and most times I see them bloating a class, is it good practice to put these each in there own class or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the listener is very long, you can implement the interfaces as [anonymous inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
something.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { 
         //Not really long and compicated code     
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Is this the preferred approach? I have seen this too quite a lot in Listener examples

Comment: @user2860598 I don't think there's a preferred approach, I prefer this when I simply have to do something not long and complicated inside the listeners..

Comment: Thank you. To keep all your Listeners together would it be a bad approach to have all your listeners in inner class's inside a main Listener class?

Comment: @user2860598 I don't see anything bad with that.

Comment: @user2860598: If there is one thing I'd recommend, it's to avoid having your GUI class (the *view*) implement a listener interface (the *controls*) as this makes the GUI class responsible for too much.